# Updating table row indexes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want  my table row numbers to get updated when a row is deleted.How can I do that with my existing code? Below is my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/arminemash/dkg6dnf6/2/

```
 <body onload="setTimeout('myFunction()', 500)">
  <div>
    <table id="myTable" border='1px'>
         <tr>
            <th>N</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>tel.</th>
            <th>email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td><button>add</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div>
</body>

var arr=[['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j','k','l'],  ['m','n','o','p'],['q','r','s','t'],['u','v','w','x']];

function myFunction() {
  createTable();  
}

function createTable(){
  var i,j,row;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    for( i=1; i<arr.length; i++ ){
         row = table.insertRow(i);
         for( j=0; j<6; j++ ){
           var cell = row.insertCell(j);    
       }    
        table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML=i;
        table.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML='<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';  
     }   
  }

 function deleteRow(r) {
     var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
     document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose a CSS solution.
Just add this to your css:

```
table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr:not(:first-child){
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Here is the link: [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dkg6dnf6/3/)

A clean solution: https://jsfiddle.net/jLe2wggx/

Comment: Remove your JavaScript row counter counter and move the button "Add" from that table

Comment: Thank you for your help.It's very interesing solution.I like it, but there is a slight problem,the last row must'nt have an index.As this is new for me can you help me plse to solve that problem?

Comment: How about that:

[link after all changes](https://jsfiddle.net/jLe2wggx/)

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much :)